# cannot pass value to ko.observableArray

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout-2.0

I am asp.net MVC developer.

In my model as follows,

```
public class GiftModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

controller=>

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

    GiftModel[] initialState = new[] {
        new GiftModel { Title = "Tall Hat", Price = 49.95 },
        new GiftModel { Title = "Long Cloak", Price = 78.25 }
    };
    return View(initialState);
}
```

but when executing I stuck here in script ,

initialValues=  ""[{\"Title\":\"Tall Hat...ak\",\"Price\":78.25}]""

```
var result = ko.observable(initialValues)
```

this output no result

Comment: Your qeustion is very unclear! What are you trying to do? Please post your actual view code html and js and also try to describe what is not working!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you need to create an observableArray, but the problem is your `initialValues` is a string. You need to convert your string into object using `JSON.parse`:

```
initialValues= JSON.parse("[{\"Title\":\"Tall Hat...ak\",\"Price\":78.25}]");
var result = ko.observableArray(initialValues)
```

Comment: @Aruni Godage: please give more information in your question.

Comment: JSON.parse() => what is does khanh ? I new to this.that return no result.

Comment: @Aruni Godage: it converts your json string into javascript object. More information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse